# Bean not autowiring from a different package

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, spring-bean

I have a configuration class. In that configuration class I am creating a bean of type `RestTemplate`. This configuraration class resides in `com.example.Config`.

I have a `Controller` in the package located in `com.example.Controller`.

In my `Main` class (which resides in `com.example.Core`), I have the following:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.Config", "com.example.Controller"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am trying to autowire the `RestTemplate` bean in my `Controller` but upon starting my app I get the following error:

```
Field `restTemplate` in `com.example.Controller.HelloWebClientController` required a bean of type `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` that could not be found.
- User-defined bean method `restTemplate` in `RestConfig`

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` in your configuration.
```

This is my config class:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its failing to autowire because spring can't find that bean. Can you post the code where you have created the RestTemplate bean?

Comment: @ArunGowda added

Comment: Just two tips to help identify problem: 1. Is the `RestTemplate` in `RestConfig` from package `org.springframework.web.client`? 2. If you move the bean to your `Main` class, would it work?

Comment: So far I've moved all the classes in the same folder as my main class for the time being, yes it works at the moment but this is not desirable. Yes the RestTemplate in RestConfig is from the org.springframework.web.client package

Comment: Can you also add the package/project structure please. I doubt that the package  `@Configuration` is in , is not scanned

Comment: Try adding another bean to same configuration file `RestConfig` and autowiring it. If this fails, there's some issue with your packaging and maybe alter something in `scanBasePackages`

Comment: @Tloz Were you able to solve the issue.?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, you can move the `Main` class to the `com.example` package (from the `core` package). In this case you can use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation without specifying the packages to scan.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Maybe it will help.